# virtualised select : How to make searchable on specific label

Tags: reactjs

Consider i have data for options like this

ObjectCodes : [{
Id: 1002
Code: "897"
Description: "truck"
CodeDescription: "897 - truck"
},
{
Id: 1089
Code: "807"
Description: "bus"
CodeDescription: "898 - bus"
},
{
Id: 8990
Code: "342"
Description: "car"
CodeDescription: "342- car"
}]

and my virtualised select is like below in react

required
    options={this.props.masterData.ObjectCodes}
    value={this.state.selectedObjectCode1}
    labelKey="CodeDescription"
    placeholder="Select Object Code 1"
    onChange={selectedObjectCode1 =>
        this.setState({
            selectedObjectCode1,
            hasErrorSelectedObjectCode1: false
        })
    }
    searchable={true}
    simpleValue
    valueKey="Id"
/>

when we search for 897  then it displays all the 3 records as it will search for the entire array (whats available in options attribute), here i want to be able to give search only on lablekey (CodeDescription). How can we achieve this.

BR/Sandesh Kirani

Comment: Show your react code for your select component. In fact, it would be best if you can create a sample on codesandbox.

Comment: @silent Here is the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/virtualised-select-dbl2l  , here search for 89 then we see all 3 get filtered as 89 is matches with ID and Code. Here i am looking at a way that i need to enable search only on CodeDescription (i.e., what ever mentioned in labelkey attribute, search should happen only on that)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - https://codesandbox.io/s/virtualised-select-ekbvd
Now, if I type "8", it only shows me two options. It searches only by CodeDescriptions. If you want further search customization, you can enable `async` and use the `loadOptions` feature.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";
import "react-virtualized-select/styles.css";
import VirtualizedSelect from "react-virtualized-select";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ObjectCodes: [
        {
          Id: 1002,
          Code: "897",
          Description: "truck",
          CodeDescription: "897 - truck"
        },
        {
          Id: 1089,
          Code: "807",
          Description: "bus",
          CodeDescription: "898 - bus"
        },
        {
          Id: 8990,
          Code: "342",
          Description: "car",
          CodeDescription: "342- car"
        }
      ],
      selectedObjectCode1: undefined
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <VirtualizedSelect
          required
          labelKey="CodeDescription"
          options={this.state.ObjectCodes}
          value={this.state.selectedObjectCode1}
          placeholder="Select Object Code"
          onChange={selectedObjectCode1 =>
            this.setState({
              selectedObjectCode1
            })
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

NOTE that library is NO LONGER MAINTAINED. I don't recommend you continuing using it.

Comment: this does not work and with customoption renderer also we dont have function that can be used to specify on what the search has to happen.